# bash script credentials for subversion

Tags: bash, shell, svn, unix, authentication

Below script works fine when username/password is right on first attempt but when i intentionally give wrong username/password it errors out. But how can i have the script to prompt username and password again if commit fails for wrong credentials ?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

read -p "Enter message: " svnmessage
read -p "Enter username: " username
read -s -p "Enter Password: " password


svn commit test.log -m "$svnmessage" --username $username --password $password --non-interactive
```

When i give wrong username/password:

```
Enter message: some message
Enter username: wrong name
Enter Password:
svn: E170001: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E170001: POST of '/svn/IL_IES_Demo/!svn/me': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (http://10.118.19.200:8080)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you can pass `--non-interactive` to `svn` to prevent this:

```
svn commit test.log -m "$svnmessage" --non-interactive --username $username --password $password
```

I'm assuming `svn commit` will return `0` on success, so (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

while true
do
    read -p "Enter message: " svnmessage
    read -p "Enter username: " username
    read -s -p "Enter Password: " password

    svn commit test.log -m "$svnmessage" --non-interactive --username $username --password $password

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: Sean..that helped - first problem (Updated question!). Thanks. Now I'm looking to have the script ask for username and password till the credentials are right.

Comment: I'd enclose _all_ variables in double quotes: `svn commit test.log -m "$svnmessage" --non-interactive --username "$username" --password "$password"`, and I'd also recommend to add the option `-r` to `read`. (Otherwise the script will fail, if the password contains, e.g., a backslash at the end or a space anywhere.)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may want to look into using svn+ssh:// authentication.  In which case you can setup a SSH public key pair with no password and have your script use that to authenticate with the SVN server.  Which is ideal for situations where you are doing non-interactive scripts, but also useful for users who are annoyed by putting in their password all the time.